# Como quitar el efecto luminosidad de una estancia y dejarla en otra

Tags: reactjs

En Three.js tengo dos estancias,una representa un cubo y otra una esfera, con el efecto Bloom ilumino estas, el problema es que dicho efecto afecta a las dos instancia, así que aún teniendo las propiedades de Bloom a cero en una de ellas, esta sigue iluminando por el efecto de la otra y no se como hacer para que una no afecte a otra. Gracias de ante mano.

```
 const Sphere = (() => {
    return (
        <group
            position={[2, 0, 0]}
        >
            <spotLight
                position={[0, 10, 5]}
            />
            <EffectComposer>
                <Bloom radius={0} kernelSize={5} luminanceThreshold={0} luminanceSmoothing={0} intensity={0} />
            </EffectComposer>
            <mesh
                scale={[1, 1, 1]}
            >
                <sphereGeometry
                    args={[0.75, 50, 50]}
                />
                <meshStandardMaterial />
            </mesh>
        </group>
    )
})
const Cube = (() => {
    return (
        <group
            position={[-2, 0, 0]}>
            <spotLight
                position={[0, 10, 5]}
            />
            <EffectComposer>
                <Bloom radius={0} kernelSize={5} luminanceThreshold={0.5} luminanceSmoothing={0.5} intensity={1} />
            </EffectComposer>
            <mesh
                scale={[1, 1, 1]}
            >
                <boxGeometry />
                <meshStandardMaterial />
            </mesh>
        </group>
    )
})
return (
    <Canvas className='canvas'>
        <OrbitControls />
        <Environment
            preset='city'
        />
        <Cube />
        <Sphere />
    </Canvas>
);
```

}

Comment: Es interesante como `Bloom` usa la misma referencia, yo tambien esperaría que cada Bloom se instanciara x separado. Yo intentariá pasar `Bloom` como `props`, o las propiedades `radius, kernelSize` etc... como `props`.